# How to test upload and download speed to Flash Media Server?

Tags: performance, flash, actionscript-3, flash-media-server

How to detect upload and download speed to Flash Media Server?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect download speed, Adobe suggests a simple method that you can read [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashMediaServer/3.5_Deving/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a0773d56e-7ffa.html)

To detect upload speed, I'm still searching for a simple solution. I found a way you can try with [this tutorial](http://www.derekentringer.com/blog/flash-media-server-streaming-speed-testing-part-1-detect-upload-download-and-latency-speeds/).